# New PC build slows down to a halt after a few hours + network speed drops

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, computer-building, gaming

I am in the process of building a new gaming PC. I have these components:

Gigabyte Z370 Aorus 7 Motherboard
I7 8700K 
16gb 3200 Corsair RGB ram
Samsung 970 Evo 1TB nvme drive
Corsair 650w power supply
Gigabyte RTX 2080 OC graphics

I have installed windows 10 enterprise, downloaded the latest windows updates (including the anniversary update from october I believe). I did a quick benchmark using Passmark, and it got a really good score (top 98th percentile).

So I start to install things like steam, RGB controller etc. After maybe an hour of use, the network connection gets slower to the point where it doesn't load any websites. Then I notice that opening apps takes a long time. Then the start menu takes more than a few seconds. Then the mouse starts locking up, and eventually the whole thing just locks up. Even restarting takes over 5 minutes to complete!

CPU/RAM/HDD seem to be running fine in task manager. No spikes in performance. Everything is running cool. I cannot see any errors in the event viewer (Except a Distributed COM error). The only odd thing I have noticed is that the Lan1 intel port is not working. Its not recognized when I try and install the intel Lan driver that is on the gigabyte website. So I am using the Killer Lan driver on the Lan2 port. Its odd that the first port doesnt light up when it gets an ethernet cable.

I have tried starting again from scratch, reformatting the M2 drive, reinstalling windows. The same thing happens after a while.

So any pointers would be really helpful!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have stated you have issue with the ethernet ports, I would focus on those.  Disable all of them in BIOS.  Then boot to Windows and test.  If everything works as it should after a few hours, you have narrowed your problem down.  At that point I would call Gigabyte for support, as either the driver is defective or the port itself is.